# Directory Path Background Setting doesn't work

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a little section

```
<div class="Pics">

            daddasddas dasdas
            <p>daddasddas dasdas</p>

        </div>
```

The CSS part is simple:

```
.Pics{
            background-image: url('Picture/Original_Doge_meme.jpg');
        }
```

And it doesnt set the wallpapaer to the doge picture. But if i use a web link it works.
VS Code sees that image, because i can open it, i even tryied just changing the background color and it worked, only if i want to set a background pic through a Directory it fails.

Answer (score 0):

you should place the image, on workplace folder and run it

```
.Pics  {
  background-image: url('Original_Doge_meme.jpg');
}
```